# Store Storage image locally

Tags: ios, swift3

When I retrieve an image from storage, it takes about 1-2 seconds. If I could save that image locally, I wouldn't have to wait. Is there any solutions to this?

Comment: yes you can save image locally in document directory, once image is downloaded save that path without "document directory path".
document directory path changes every time you run your app, so you have to give that path dynamically. Hope this help.

Comment: @RatneshShukla thanks! but could I know where I could find this "document directory path"? or could you give me an example code? I am new to coding so please understand.

Comment: let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("apple.jpg")

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: "apple.jpg")
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFileAtPath(paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

Comment: @RatneshShukla thanks! is would UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5) the maximum compression that jpeg can represent?

Comment: @DongHaeJANG what is your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **SDWebImage** library to download (JPEG, PNG, ...) images from firebase storage. You need to pass the 'URL' of the image, you wish to download.

It is asynchronous image downloader with memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling and guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times and much more.
Please go through, it's really nice!

Here the links, https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go.